# U2F Application ID (Facet ID) for a web site

Tags: two-factor-authentication, fido-u2f

The [u2f dev guide](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/App_ID.html) leaves this part unspecified: will a single-facet AppId without the www prefix work for a visitor who accesses the site with the www-prefix? Will browsers consider them a match?

If not, I believe there are two alternatives for U2F deployments, neither very pleasant IMO - I explain below why so:

1. Redirect all web users from www.example.com to example.com then use "example.com" facet.
2. Provide a JSON resource which describes at least two facets: www.example.com, example.com

Now, I said that having to deal with the "www." explicitly isn't pleasant. My rationale is that single-site SSL certificates (including more diligent ones like EV-certs) deal with the www-prefix URLs transparently to web users. I see no reason why U2F would consider this a security hole and required an explicit way to deal with it.

Comment: Let's say that a user has registered a U2F device with foo.appspot.com. Now malicious.appspot.com shouldn't be able to trick the user into authenticating at malicious.appspot.com, using the private key minted for foo.appspot.com.

Comment: This isn't the intention -- we are talking about www.example.com vs example.com. In other words, www should be a permitted alias for no-www URL. All other sub-domains ought to be treated explicitly, per spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will not consider them a match unless there is a JSON resource that supports this. See FIDO AppID and Facet Specification v1.0: [Section 3.1 Processing Rules for AppID and FacetID Assertions](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-ps-20141009/fido-appid-and-facets-ps-20141009.html#processing-rules-for-appid-and-facetid-assertions).

Comment: I accepted your answer -- since I asked about "match vs no match" -- but I dislike how the spec forces U2F deployments to explicitly deal with the www alias.